# Custom array-like type in c++

Tags: c++, types

In a program I am writing, I need to use often integer arrays of length 3 and I thought I should define a custom type. The integers they will hold are between 0 and 2, so `int8` is more than enough. My goal is to avoid having to check explicitly for length.

I could do something of the form:

```
class MyArr {
    int8_t a;
    int8_t b;
    int8_t c;
}
```

but I would also like to be able to access the elements using `[]`, e.g. to be able to write `x[0]` instead of `x.a`. What is the optimal way to do that?

Also I guess I have to check that the values are legal, i.e. between 0 and 2 in the constructor. Is there any better way?

Comment: Overload `operator[]`?

Comment: Use an array? Small arrays do exist.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I would guess that the compiler can take advantage of the fact that the array will always have length 3. Am I wrong assuming that?

Comment: @tst sure... but that's exactly what arrays do too. `std::array<int8_t, 3>` will *always* have 3 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way is to use `std::array` and if you want bounds checking you can use the `at()` function instead of `operator[]`.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at

Example:

```
#include <array>
std::array<int8_t, 3> data = { 1, 2, 4 };
 
// Set element 1
data.at(1) = 88;
```

Comment: Congratulations on your first up-vote Cedric.  May I suggest you decorate your answer with a sample declaration of `std::array<int8_t, 3>` ?  And show the necessary header file.

Comment: And on the second.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array. Use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you want value semantics. If you use this type very often and want a name more meaningful than a generic "array", you can use a type alias:

```
// Example with a 3D vector
using vec3D = std::array<std::int8_t, 3>;

vec3D v1, v2; // 3D vectors
```